# Enable external RSS feeds without changing web.config

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, rss

I am attempting to add a RSS Feed web part that pulls from an external source and everything I have found says I have to change the `web.config` which unfortunately is extremely hard to do for me due to permissions and such.

Is there anyway to enable an external web part without changing the `web.config`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why you need proxy, when SharePoint install behind the Proxy eveything works except access to external content such as RSS feed..

Once Proxy access was granted, the web.config files on each of the servers need to be changed to inform SharePoint to use the Proxy.

For an explanation of the defaultProxy node see [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kd3cf2ex(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kd3cf2ex%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

And for an explanation of the default node see [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sa91de1e(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sa91de1e%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

In short, you have to change the web.config file and its one time activity should be part of SharePoint configuration.

other method is use some code to make changes in the web.config file.